# Is using Xampp/Wamp necessary or just a choice?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, xampp, wamp

All the people I have seen working with php, were using Wamp or Xampp. And when I spoke with them as a fellow learner, their first question was which one I use(Wamp or Xampp).

> ### Is Xampp/Wamp Server truly necessary to use or just my choice?

I first installed apache httpd server, then months later I installed Mysql community server and again months later php.I didn't plan to use them together, but now that I need to use them together, I am confused whether I should install Xampp/Wamp or it is fine without them.

> Can serious and functional development can be done without using any of them?
>
> > I don't want to realize midway that I am going into wrong direction and it is not possible.I am not asking if it is recommended for ease of use or saving time. I have no trouble in learning to configure any of them and I have done so in past with very little trouble.
> >
> > I would like to have an answer saying clearly whether I HAVE to use them, or they are just a matter of choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have done all the work of installing an AMP stack on Windows already then there is absolutely no reason to install WAMPServer or XAMPP.

These 2 products just make the process of installing a working AMP stack easier, they do not add anything over and above what you have managed to do all for yourself.

So when friends ask which product you use, all you need tell then is that you use a WAMP Stack that you installed and configured yourself.

I will add a couple of things though

- WAMPServer does allow you to have multiple versions of Apache,MySQL and PHP installed in a way that makes it easy to switch versions of all 3 parts of the AMP stack very easily. In a development environment, I personally find this extremely useful. It means I can mimic a clients environment in a couple of seconds and at the touch of a couple menu items.
- XAMPP does come with Perl.

Answer (score 0):

If you want,you can download and integrate PHP in your invironment.
But if you want everything at one place then go for Wamp or Xampp.

Comment: yes, I have already downloaded php and put it in the environment path. As I said, I already have been using them separately. I wanted to ask if Wamp/Xampp were necessary to install.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for the question is "it is just a choice". Because you can install all the software separately or all in one using WAMP/XAMPP

Comment: Thank you for the simple 'yes or no'. Could you please tell about the increase in complexity with the size of project.